# How to use Inner Join in MS Access with column name with space

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, inner-join

I  have two table **Business** and **Territory** where Business.Territory maps to Territory."Territory ID". When I am trying to join these tables, I am getting error "**Invalid use of '.','!', or '()' in query expression**" . I am using below query:

```
select * from
    Business INNER JOIN Territory
    ON Business.Territory = Territory."Territory ID"
```

When I remove double quotes and replace with square brackets ([]), it asks for parameter value in pop-up. Please note "Territory ID" is as it is (with space).

How can I join these tables. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hve to use brackets:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM Business AS b
INNER JOIN Territory AS t ON b.Territory_ID = t.Territory_ID
```

Comment: I have tried this, it asks for Parameter value in a pop-up

Comment: What does it pop up for, is it `Territory ID`.  Are you sure that you don't have something misspelled or missing an underscore?  Maybe the field is actually `Territory_ID`?  It will ask you to enter  a parameter value if it can't find the field in the table.

Comment: It pops up for b.Territory

Comment: Check the `Business` table and see if `Territory` exists and is spelled right.

Comment: Oh, got it its my fault, I was using the column aliases, actual column name us Territory_ID. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Business
INNER JOIN Territory
ON Business.Territory = Territory.`Territory ID`
```

The key is the `` around Territory ID - ` is located next to 1 on your keyboard (UK keyboard at least). Any Column name with a space requires these.